# Display multiple items when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up multiple items to show when a checkbox is selected. If you choose Function 1 for example I want all the steps related to function 1 to appear.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Function 1: <input type="checkbox" id="function1"  onclick="myFunction(this.id, 'function1_steps')">
Function 2: <input type="checkbox" id="function2"  onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="function1_1" class="function1_steps" style="display:none">Function1 Step 1:</p>
<p id="function1_2" class="function1_steps" style="display:none">Function1 Step 2:</p>


</body>
</html>

function myFunction(id, pid) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
  var text = document.getElementsByClass(pid);
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (first checkbox shows the 2 step, second one none, so you can see multiple by class)

```js
$('#function1').click(function() {
    $(".function1_steps").toggle(this.checked);
});

$('#function2').click(function() {
    //...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Function 1: <input type="checkbox" id="function1">
Function 2: <input type="checkbox" id="function2">

<p id="function1_1" class="function1_steps" style="display:none">Function1 Step 1:</p>
<p id="function1_2" class="function1_steps" style="display:none">Function1 Step 2:</p>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT (to explain): 
The syntax I used is pretty simple and it's the basic of JQuery.

```
$('#function1').click(function() {
    $(".function1_steps").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

This just check if the input with id = 'function' is clicked, independently if it is a button, a checkbox, a radio button, etc. IDs are called like that one. With # calls for an ID, using . calls for a class

```
$('#function1')        //Input with 'function1' as id
$('.function1')        //Input with 'function1' as class
```

This just calls the

associated to the class 'function1_steps' and use the function toggle (basically it shows the div, or p, or whatever if it's hided, and it hides it if it's showing)

```
$(".function1_steps").toggle(this.checked);
```

this.checked means that you're checking if the checkbox is checked or not and execute the toggle if it is checked (true)

Comment: @gobiwankenobi You're welcome...i edited with some explanations if you want to check it out

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation! Makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `id` attribute.

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
  var text = document.getElementById(id+"_text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Function 1: <input type="checkbox" id="function1" onclick="myFunction(this.id)"> Function 2: <input type="checkbox" id="function2" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">

<p id="function1_text" class="function1_steps" style="display:none">Function1 Step 1:</p>
<p id="function2_text" class="function1_steps" style="display:none">Function2 Step 2:</p>
```

Comment: I wanted to display Step 1 and 2 when I clicked on Function 1 checkbox, not displaying step 1 with Function 1 and Step 2 with Function 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `data-* attribute` to set which step you're using, so as to not tie it to the ID (although it's a matter of your personal preference).

After that, get all the elements with classname `function${step}_steps`:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  const step = e.dataset.step;
  const steps = document.getElementsByClassName(`function${step}_steps`);

  for (let i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
    if (e.checked == true) {
      steps[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      steps[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Function 1: <input type="checkbox" data-step='1' onclick="myFunction(this)">
Function 2: <input type="checkbox" data-step='2'  onclick="myFunction(this)">

<p class="function1_steps" style="display:none" data-step='1'>Function1 Step 1:</p>
<p class="function1_steps" style="display:none" data-step='1'>Function1 Step 2:</p>


</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Sending `this` as an argument to the function will allow you to target the element itself, without having to do one more search for the right checkbox :)